# How to write to cygwin pipe from c#

Tags: c#, pipe, cygwin

I want to create a c# app that can be used in a cygwin pipe with "tail -f".

i.e.

> tail -f SomeFile | MyCSharpApp

I can see (from debugging) that I am able to read stdinput correctly, but nothing is written back to cygwin terminal windows.

However,

> tail -n10 SomeFile | MyCSharpApp

Works perfectly.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string s;
        while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           //Potentially process s here
           Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So it isn't a C# problem

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I think it is. Both tail -f and tail -n10 work when I do NOT include my app in pipe.

Comment: Cygwin, huh, good god yo.  Slurp all the input first so you can't deadlock on the pipe buffer size.

Comment: @HansPassant Would you suggest how I do that with Tail -f being continuous?

Comment: I'm confused by this statement in your post:

"I can see (from debugging) that I am able to read stdinput correctly, but nothing is written back to cygwin terminal windows."

When you say that you are able to read stdin correctly, what do you mean? Is Console.ReadLine returning information?

Out of curiosity, have you tried Console.Read instead of Console.ReadLine?

Comment: I mean that if I step through with VS debugger I can see the lines coming in one by one, in my loop. ReadLine works, it is the the output that doesn't

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what have been happening with SomeFile. `tail -f SomeFile` opens the SomeFile file descriptor and monitors it. If the descriptor somehow changed, for an example, you have opened the file in notepad and clicked "Save", nothing would have been monitored. It happens because notepad deletes the file and writes new one with the same name. I would recommend to try `tail -F SomeFile`. **-F** reopens a file descriptor.

Comment: I have tried both - same issue. The file is a constantly updated log file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer was written wrongly about the opposite of the issue. That is to say that it was written for attempting `myApp > tail -f` and not `tail -f file.txt > myApp`.

`tail -f` works on a file and not a pipe.  The only way that I can get it to output the output of another command is if I use `tail -F <(ls -lthr)` where `ls -lthr` could be any command that prints output.

Let's think about why this is.  `tail` prints the contents of a file (particularly the the lines at the end).  If you have the ability to print to the console or stdout then you do not need `tail`.

Extra: and furthermore if you decided that you needed to output into a file then you could simply use `> file.txt` to put that console output into a file.

Comment: I need tail because this is a constantly updating log file

Comment: @ManInMoon somehow I managed to completely get your intention backwards.  I thought that you were trying to output through tail and not take input through tail.  The issue With what you are trying to do is that the pipe provides the data through as an argument to the next command. This is done once and not in an ongoing way.  It would likely be a better idea for your application to check the file intermittently for changes. Once you know the last line number from a previous check then you could start at the next line. I've never actually seen any recommendation to ever pipe `tail -f'  output

Comment: take a look at this question that seems to answer the real issue: https://superuser.com/questions/742238/piping-tail-f-into-awk